# Nginx [sites-enabled]

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I've just installed nginx 0.7.67 via passenger-install-nginx-module. Previously it was 0.7.65 which was compiled from source. After the new install, i deleted all the old files including the binary in /sbin folder. I also did a search 'find / -name nginx.conf' and the old files are no longer there.

The problem now is, this mongrel instance that was supposed to run on only one subdomain appears on other subdomains that were listed in sites-enabled folder. But I've already deleted it. why is this still happening?

My nginx folder /opt/nginx/ does not have sites-enabled and sites-available, so could it be that nginx is still caching the old info?

Comment: Nginx does not cache the configuration file at all. If you've reloaded the binary when you upgraded then the new configuration file should be in effect. Use nginx -V to see which config file it loads by default and paste that one so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I get the following for nginx -V 

-bash: nginx: command not found

Comment: Try /opt/nginx/bin/nginx